# How to format the default date for timeago_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

I'm using the format below to display my time ago but need help understanding how to do the format for the default date format. Using `rails-timeago` gem:

```
=timeago_tag Time.zone.now, :nojs => true, :limit => 2.days.ago, lang: :en

print>> 2d
```

After that it does the `yyyy-dd-mm` format.

I would like to format the default date like `May 22, 2014`. There's a `(:strftime,'%B %d, %Y')` that I've used in other format to display how I wanted it but I'm not sure how the syntax works with the `timeago_tag` helper.

Comment: In the [rails-timeago README](https://github.com/jgraichen/rails-timeago) there is an option for **format**... Will it work if you add `format: "%B %d, %Y"` after `lang: :en,`?

Comment: That was it! I've tried different variations of that but it didn't work, just needed someone to tell me. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in the comments, `timeago_tag` has a `format` option, so to get your date in the format `"%B %d, %Y"`:

```
= timeago_tag Time.zone.now, nojs: true, limit: 2.days.ago, lang: :en, format: "%B %d, %Y"
```